# Как передать GET параметр

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, get

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с задачей передачи GET параметра  в ссылку. При переходе к пример с фейсбука,  нужно подставить в ссылку другой номер  телефона и другой её параметр.
К примеру  у меня есть  ссылка с номером :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Её код:

```
<a href="tel:035430322" class="mob_bottom">
        03-5430322
</a>
```

Мне нужно как-то реализовать, что  бы при переходе к примеру  с того же фейсбука  эта ссылка меняла свое значение  на следующий:

```
<a  href="http://example?/tel=4352235643" class="mob_bottom">
        4356435643
    </a>
```

Не судите строго, ещё  учусь
Буду благодарен  за  любую подробную информацию!

Comment: Не совсем понятно, откуда Вы берете параметры. Я правильно понял, что при клике на линку на фейсбуке, Вам нужно, чтобы Ваш сайт/приложение открывалось с разными параметрами? Т.е., если это переход с фейсбука - подставляет один параметр. Если это прямое открытие, - оставляем все, как есть?

Comment: @Mr.Brightside:  Да, вы абсолютно правы. Нужно сделеать именно так. как это реализовать? Подскажите пожалуйста!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то есть 2 кейса.

**Переход по линке с Facebook**

Думаю, что на facebook у вас есть некая группа, где вы указываете ссылки для перехода на Ваш сайт.

В этом случае, эту ссылку на фейсбуке можно сделать такой:

```
my-link-on-my-website.com?tel=11111
```

Далее, при загрузке уже вашего сайта, смотреть, что есть в url и в зависимости от этого менять содержимое контейнера:

```
window.onload = function() { //onLoad запустится при загрузке сайта
  var url_string = window.location.href
  var url = new URL(url_string);
  var param = url.searchParams.get("tel");

  if(param) { //Если есть параметр, то выполняем замену текста
      var link = document.getElementById('myLink');
      link.href = 'http://example?/tel=4352235643';
      link.innerHTML = '4352235643';
  }
};
```

И Ваша разметка поменяется на:

```
<a  href="http://example?/tel=4352235643" class="mob_bottom" id='myLink'>
    4356435643
</a>
```

Что такое onLoad и как его кушать описано [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/onload)

**Прямой переход**

При прямом переходе в адресной строке не будет параметров. Событие onLoad все также вызовется, но ничего не сделает, как раз из-за отсутствия параметров.

*Важно*

Я просто привел пример, как это можно сделать, но это лишь один из возможных вариантов. К тому же, требующий более щепетильных проверок.

- Если вы используете фреймворк, то это может помочь Вам выполнить подобную обработку
- Я бы проверял, так же, значение параметра. Дело в том, что GET параметры может подставить в ссылку любой и, если вы будете просто проверять, если ли параметр tel или нет, то выводимое в Вашей ссылки значение может оказаться неожиданным =)
- Кроме того, возможно решение через просмотр истории, если у Вас есть доступ к бэкенду. JavaScript не позволяет получать доступ к предыдущим URL, только к навигации.

Надеюсь, это поможет

Comment: Спасибо Вам  огромное за подробный  ответ!

Answer (score 0):

PHP - `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

JS - `document.referrer`

Нужная вам информация хранится там. Получили и в зависимости от результата вывели все что вам нужно.